# Exception in text entries when running iOS tests on XTC

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

We are trying to setup test runs on Xamarin Test Cloud and are running into the below issue very often.

For example for login scenario, sometimes the keyboard is not visible to enter text and I get the below exception:

> Error while performing EnterText("XXXXXX")
>
> Exception: System.Exception: No keyboard is visible for text entry.
>     at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSApp+c__AnonStorey5.<>m__0 () <0x69f0838 + 0x0011f> in :0 
>     at Xamarin.UITest.Utils.ErrorReporting.With (System.Action func, System.Object[] args, System.String memberName) <0x69e0988 + 0x00030> in :0

I do not believe adding a wait time is the best solution. Have you faced this issue? Any suggestions on what is the best solution for this?

Comment: Can you show your syntax for the test & give some more information on why you don't think adding a wait time would help?

Comment: Thanks a lot Kent for your response. We fixed the issue (for now) by adding a 'waitforkeyboard' before all text entries. Wait time was not working out for us because it was difficult to find a optimum time - sometimes it is 2 secconds, sometimes 5 and sometimes 10. (all this was for tests run on the cloud, so I dont have more information like fail logs etc; dont see this error on the local run.

Comment: It's typical for test runs to take longer in the Cloud than locally; for example this guide notes that the default wait time for a local UITest is 15 seconds, but in Test Cloud is 1 minute. However, if you manually set the timeout that overrides them: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/timeouts/.

Comment: @Kiran, For the sake of future Users/Viewers, if the answer below solves your issue, please mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 7):

**Are you using `Xamarin.UITest 2.0.0`**?

- There is a known issue in `Xamarin.UITest 2.0.0`

  > [iOS] EnterText() can occasionally be slow or throw errors.
- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/80108/xamarin-uitest-2-0-0-supporting-ios-10-and-xcode-8-released

**Add a Longer `WaitForElement()`**

- As Kent suggested in the comments above, use a longer `WaitForElement`. Perhaps 90 seconds?  If the element is found in a shorter time, you won't wait the full 90 seconds.
- `app.WaitForElement(c=>c.Marked("success_message_label"), "Did not see the success message."), new TimeSpan(0,0,1,30,0));`
- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/timeouts/

**Try Thread.Sleep(*milliseconds*) in the UITest**

- If you're not keen on using `WaitForElement`, you could always use `Thread.Sleep(5000);` to pause the UITest, allowing the phone to catch up.  I personally use this myself when working with older phones.
- https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Threading.Thread.Sleep/p/System.Int32/

**Also note *(for future viewers)* that when testing on iOS locally**

- `IApp.EnterText` will fail if the simulator is configured to use the `hardware keyboard`. Before running your UITests locally, ensure that the simulator is configured to use the soft keyboard.
- Simulator >> Hardware >> Keyboard >> Uncheck "Connect Hardware Keyboard"
- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/entering-text/#Disable_the_Hardware_Keyboard